# Is it possible to measure pressure in a vacuum using light?

Tags: visible-light, pressure, vacuum

I was wondering if it possible to measure the pressure in a vacuum using light.

Answer (score 0):

For ideal gases at a constant temperature, we have that

$$n-1 = Ap$$

for some constant $A$. After calibration, measuring the refractive index of the gas using geometric methods should give you the pressure.

Comment: but then it wouldn't be vacuum...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Well, if you meant a perfect vacuum, then there's no gas, so there's no pressure.

Comment: yeah the question is ambiguous as stated, since it is not clear what pressure the OP wants to measure.

Comment: And interferometric experiments can give you *very* high precision in measuring $n$. But there are some hitches. First, interferometry makes it easy to measure *change* in $n$, but you need an absolute reference to measure the *value* of $n$. And second the right reference is a complete vaccuum which is, well, hard to obtain.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I assumed the question was non-trivial and gave the answer accordingly. Arguments over semantics are not useful for practical questions.

Comment: @probably_someone - Measuring the index of refraction of the gas may work at pressures near standard atmospheric pressure, but my feeling is that once the pressure gets down to the milli-Torr range and below it will be extremely difficult to impossible to get accurate readings of the pressure by measuring the index of refraction. Don't expect any sort of laser-based index of refraction vacuum gauges to replace standard vacuum gauges anytime soon.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Fair point. This is the only way that I could think of, so I posted it as a possibility.